# Setting data-content and displaying popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get data from a resource with jquery's ajax and then I try to use this data to populate a bootstrap popover, like this:

```
$('.myclass').popover({"trigger": "manual", "html":"true"});
$('.myclass').click(get_data_for_popover_and_display);
```

and the function for retrieving data is:

```
get_data_for_popover_and_display = function() {
    var _data = $(this).attr('alt');
    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/myresource',
         data: _data,
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function(data) {
             $(this).attr('data-content', data);
             $(this).popover('show');
         }
    });
}
```

What is happening is that the popover is NOT showing when I click, but if I hover the element later it will display the popover, but without the content (the `data-content` attribute). If I put an `alert()` inside the `success` callback it will display returned data.

Any idea why is happening this? Thanks!

Comment: `function {` should be `function() {` — does that affect anything?

Comment: No, just forgot to add parenthesis. Fixed in example, thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your success callback, `this` is no longer bound to the same value as in the rest of `get_data_for_popover_and_display()`.

Don't worry! The `this` keyword is hairy; misinterpreting its value is a common mistake in JavaScript.

You can solve this by keeping a reference to `this` by assigning it to a variable:

```
get_data_for_popover_and_display = function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var _data = el.attr('alt');
    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/myresource',
         data: _data,
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function(data) {
             el.attr('data-content', data);
             el.popover('show');
         }
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could write `var that = this;` and use `$(that)` everywhere. More solutions and background [here](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/).

Comment: Great, instead of just show me how to fix it, you showed my why it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I sometimes use $this as my var name.

Comment: if i dont want use "attr" in "el.attr('data-content', data)" then what is the solution? it is possible to use "data('content', response)"?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer above, don't forget that according to [$.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can use the **context** parameter to achieve the same result without the extra variable declaration as such:

```
get_data_for_popover_and_display = function() {
    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/myresource',
         data: $(this).attr('alt'),
         dataType: 'html',
         context: this,
         success: function(data) {
             $(this).attr('data-content', data);
             $(this).popover('show');
         }
    });
}
```