# Twitter Bootstrap Popup ignores delay

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, delay, popover

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130069/load-bootstrap-js-popover-content-with-ajax) here on stackoverflow, I created a twitter bootstrap popover that loads on hover. However, the delay is not used, the popover just shows immediately. Here's my code:

```
$('body').delegate('.withajaxpopover', 'hover', function(event) {
   if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {
      var el=$(this);
      $.get(el.attr('data-load'), function(d) {
      el.popover({delay: { 
                     show: 750, 
                     hide: 100
                  },
                  title: "MyTitle", 
                  content: d}).popover('show', 
                                       {delay: { show: 750, hide: 100 }});
                    });
   } else {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
   }
});
$('body').delegate('.withajaxpopover', 'click', function(event) {
   $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

The delay is just ignored. What can I do?

Thanks for your help or hints!

Comment: Did you know that delay `does not apply to manual trigger type` ? [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) - and doing `popover('show')` is like manual. And passing an object as 2nd parameter will certainly have no effect at all.

Comment: No, I did not know that before. But how can I show the popover, if not using `popover('show')`?

Comment: Delay and popovers are kind of messy... [github issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/512). Would that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ERY4S/) work ?

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar issue, solved it by focusing the obj. Would look something like this...

```
$('#yourobj').popover({
    trigger: 'focus',
    delay: 1000
 }).focus();
```

even better with a timeout, if you want a manual trigger..

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#yourobj').popover('show');
}, 500);
```

Hope is helps someone else...