# Is it possible to assign an id to a Twitter Bootstrap popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been able to get the Twitter Bootstrap popovers to show but is there a way to assign id's to them on creation so I can manipulate them?

Heres my code so far:
.js

```
$('#test-button').popover({content:'test.', trigger:'click'});
$('#test-button').popover('show');
```

.html

```
<a id='test-button' rel='popover'>
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of options you could use to get the popover element:

1) Modify [Boostrap Popover](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-popover.js) to accept an id property on the options object and inject that into the template (line: 102)

2) Set the html property on popover options using an id e.g.

```
$('#test-button').popover({html: true, content: '<div id="test-popover-content">... </div>'})
```

and then access the popover container via

```
var testPopover = $('#test-popover-content').parent().parent();
```

Comment: This should actually be:
`$('#test-button').popover({html: true, content: '<div id="test-popover-content">... </div>'})`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to specify a [template](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) with the id you want.

> Base HTML to use when creating the popover.
>
> The popover's title will be injected into the .popover-title.
>
> The popover's content will be injected into the .popover-content.
>
> .arrow will become the popover's arrow.
>
> The outermost wrapper element should have the .popover class.

Here's the default template value :

```
 '<div class="popover" role="tooltip">
     <div class="arrow"></div>¸
     <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
     <div class="popover-content"></div>
  </div>'
```

And you can use it like this

```
$(#your-pop-over).popover({
     template:'<div id="your-id" class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'       
    });
```

Comment: Be careful—you can't set an ID on the .popover container, as it will be overwritten to something like #popover50000.