# Twitter Bootstrap Popover and AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I been browsing SO for solutions on how to load an ajax content on bootstrap popover but can't find any decent solutions.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(".btnCharge").click(function () {
    $("#boxPayment").fadeIn();
})
.popover({
    title: 'Advantages',
    html: 'true',
    content: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Index.aspx/FindAdvantagesByCCID",
            data: '{"id": "' + 1 + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                var html = '';
                $.each(json, function (i, item) {
                    html = html + '<a href="#"><i class="icon-ok"></i>' + item.Advantage + '</a><br />';
                });
            }
        });
    },
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

How can i add the ajax response to popover content? I tried "return" and doesnt work.

Any clean solutions?

Answer (score 10):

Yes. it is possible. And it has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105085) already.

Using `data-` attributes you can provide the URL, like here:

```
<a href="#" title="blabla" data-ajaxload="/test.php">blabla</a>
```

Now the handler:

```
$('*[data-ajaxload]').bind('hover',function(){
  var e=$(this);
  e.unbind('hover');
  $.get(e.data('ajaxload'),function(d){
      e.popover({content: d}).popover('show');
  });
});
```

`unbind('hover')` prevents loading data more than once and popover() binds a new hover event. If you want the data to be refreshed at every hover event, you should modify this a bit.

Comment: how about the params? i need to pass parent id thru ajax call

Comment: Which params are you talking about?

Comment: As I said, `data-ajaxload` is the parameter. Didn't you read the answer?

Comment: Aint that the path for the call?
Don't need to be rude :)

Comment: I am not rude. **Sorry**, if it sounded that way. Now, I don't get you. You wanted to load some data using AJAX, say from `/test.php`, and you need to give that way. This goes into the content of the Popover. :)

Comment: I need to call a Webmethod. Say it Index.aspx/FindAdvantagesByCCID passing an ID parameter, just like the original question. take a look on my ajax call. THEN i'll add the result to the popover, but need to send the param.
NP :D

Comment: Hey, just replace the line from `$.get(` till the first `});` with your code, `$.ajax(` till its `});`. :) Simple. Get it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24058/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-user1910498)

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out. Been fighting with this for quite awhile now. Keep in mind that instead of `get`, you can use `ajax` method and pass url through that parameter rather than data attribute.

Comment: @EternalHour You are welcome. **1.** `$.get` is a shorthand for `$.ajax`. Literally no difference. **2.** Passing the url is not okay in this case, because it's dynamic based on the popover selected. The URL for each event will be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access to popover option data like this:

```
popoverData = $('.myPopover').data('popover')
```

So, you can do this to change popover content since it cant be changed once it is set.

```
if (popoverData = $('.myPopover').data('popover'))
{
    popoverData.options.content = newContent;
}

$('.myPopover').popover({ content: newContent, html:true, trigger:'hover' }).popover("show");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Html like this...

Id is present in your loop. You will use this value to retrieve additional information (ajax).

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach:persons">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                    <td ><span data-bind="popOver: {content : $root.contentData, id: id}"</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

In your viewModel you have a variable
  - this variable is initially empty.

```
 var contentData = ko.observable();
```

Add a custom binding handler like:

```
> ko.bindingHandlers.popOver = {
>     init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
>         var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
> 
>         var options = {
>             placement: 'top',
>             title: "Title",
>             html: true,
>             trigger: 'manual',
>             content: value.content
>         };
> 
>         $(element).popover(options);
> 
> 
> 
> 
>         $(element).click(function () {
>             var id = value.id();
>             var response = myApp.GetAdditionalData(id);
>             value.content(response.content);
> 
>             $(this).popover('toggle');
>         });
>     } };
```

Outside your viewModel you will have a function making the ajax call:

```
 var GetAdditionalDataFromAjax = function (id) {
      return { "content": "some content returned by id"};
```