# Unable to load remote html using bootstrap popover (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to load remote html data using bootstrap popover.
Below is my code. I tried this from below

[Load a Bootstrap popover content with AJAX. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130069/load-bootstrap-js-popover-content-with-ajax)

```
<a href="#" id="oneData" class="divAnchor" rel="popover" 
           load-remote-data="TestGetJson.htm">Bootstrap popover with ajax data</a>
```

Below code is inside script tag. When I debug using firebug i get response from server 
But it is not shown in the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#oneData').bind('click',function(){
        var e=$(this);
        //e.unbind('click');
        $.get(e.attr('load-remote-data'),function(data){
            e.popover({content: data, placement:'bottom', html:true}).popover('show');
        });
     });
});
```

Response from server

```
<div class="popover fade bottom in" ><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title">pop Over Title</h3><div class="popover-content">Data From Server</div></div>
```

used below imports in my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap-popover.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-popover.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Thanks. I do not know that we can check javascript error in the firebug console. Its solved. Problem with the file "js/bootstrap-popover.min.js". It has no popover method.

Comment: @suresh - Welcome to Stack Overflow. Great your problem was solved! Consider adding an answer to your own question, so that everybody knows your problem was solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Marijn I have less than 10 reputation. So I will add answer in  8 hours.

Comment: That would be great. Many people (me too) check if there are unanswered questions, so adding an answer is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with wrong file import. So marking this question as answered.