# How to change content of a bootstrap popover that has already been displayed?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a form with a password entered twice. I check password complexity and consistency and display appropriate error messages into a popover attached to the INPUT field:

```
<a href="#" id="aIdPwd2" data-toggle="manual" data-content="The password entered does not match the one previously entered" data-placement="right" href="#" rel="popover">
<input type="password" id="iIdPwd2" class="fmt1" size="60" value=""/>
</a>
```

With this code:

```
$("#aIdPwd2").popover({content: msg});
```

You can chose dynamicaly the message that will be displayed. But once it has been displayed once, it will then always remain the same.

I read many articles about this popular issue and did try many things (attach 2 different popover to the same input, change the inner html in the getElementsByClassName("popover-content"), destroy and recreate the popover, ..), but without any success so far.

A solution on how to change content of a bootstrap popover that has already been displayed or any kind of work-around would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("popover-content")[0].innerHTML = 'something else';
```

sure that this doesn't work?

tried it on [this page](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-example.html#) and it works as expected.

**UPDATE:** it will work only if the popover is visible because the element is recreated/destroyed every mouseover/mouseout event

i guess it's not the best solution, but you can do this:

```
var msg = 'ben123 is not a goddamn password!';

document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {  
    document.getElementsByClassName("popover-content")[0].innerHTML = msg; 
});
```

and change `msg` when you need

Comment: I've made a few more tests with this solution and found a few interresting things: 1) You need to make the $("#example").popover('show'); prior to set anything into document.getElementsByClassName("popover-content")[0].innerHTML or the element will not exist and this will cause an error. 2) If you trigger the javascript that display/set from the button, then you suffer from some tricky side effects, the popver being hidden automaticaly despite the data-toggle="manual", causing an error and messing the full chain of events. If you can deal with those 2 limitations, then it works.

Comment: Can you share your test code, so I can check if I didn't miss anything?

Comment: when you close a modal in bootstrap all its html will be removed so you are not going to find anything by  getElementsByClassName("popover-content") for that modal

Answer (score 14):

In Twitter Bootstrap 3, I just update the content and then call `show`. Calling of the `show` ensure that its resized correctly and then positioned correctly.

```
$(".notes").data("bs.popover").options.content="Content1";
$(".notes").popover("show");
$(".notes").data("bs.popover").options.content="Content2";
$(".notes").popover("show");
```

If you are using data tags to show the content then you will need to update the data tag as that takes precedence. eg.

```
$(".notes").attr("data-content","Content1");
$(".notes").popover("show");
$(".notes").attr("data-content","Content2");
$(".notes").popover("show");
```

I like the second option better coz it doesn;t access the internals by doing `data(bs.popover)` **but** the first options is much faster as it doesn't update the dom. So pick what floats your boat.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with solutions that rely on `popover('show')` is that if you do this in an event handler for the `show` event, you will end up with an infinite loop.

If you just want to display some content in your popover *when it has already been shown*, you will need to directly modify the DOM:

```
$("#aIdPwd2").next(".popover").find(".popover-content").html(msg);
```

For example, if you want a popover that will load some data from an API and display that in the popover's content on hover:

DOM:

```
<a href="#" id="myPopover" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Details" data-api-parameter="someValue">Hover here for details</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#myPopover").popover({
    trigger: 'hover'
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    var popover = $(this);
    var contentEl = popover.next(".popover").find(".popover-content");
    // Show spinner while waiting for data to be fetched
    contentEl.html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw'></i>");

    var myParameter = popover.data('api-parameter');
    $.getJSON("http://api.example.com", {
        'apiParameter': myParameter
    }).done(function (data) {
        var result = data['apiReturnValue'];
        contentEl.html(result);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        result = "No info found.";
        contentEl.html(result);
    });
});
```

This, of course, assumes that you trust the data supplied by api.example.com.  If not, you will probably want to escape the data returned to mitigate XSS attacks.

Answer (score 3):

To replace the contents of a popover on an element, first call destroy.
Tested on Bootstrap 3.1.1

```
$("#aIdPwd2").popover('destroy').popover({content: msg});
```