# Bootstrap popover with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a popover with dynamic content loaded with ajax.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130069/load-bootstrap-js-popover-content-with-ajax/9105085#9105085) but since my problem is different, I cannot fit it the answer

Here is my html code:

```
<a id='{{user}}' class="manager" href="#" rel="popover" onclick="getValue(this)">{{user}}</a>
```

and here the jquery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function getValue(control)
            {
            var id = $(control).attr('id');
            $('#loadingDiv').show();
            $("#manager").hide()


            $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_jquerymanagerdetails', 

            {'id':id}
            ,

            function(data) {

            $("#manager").html(data.html);
            $("#manager").show()
            $('#loadingDiv').hide();
            });

        return false;
        };

</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
  var div = '<div id="manager"></div>
  $('[rel="popover"]').popover({ title: 'Look! A bird!', content: div, html:true, placement:"right"});
</script>
```

Until now, I've had another div with `id="manager"` and I load all the content there. But I want to do it on a popover and I think that it's kind of weird.

Comment: use bootstrap popover selector option to delegate popover plugin http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: @A.Wolff Do you mean something like the above? I change the question with your suggestion, but still I cannot make it work.

Comment: i don't know bootstrap enough, but i guess you should try: `$('body').popover({ selector: '[rel="popover"]',title: 'Look! A bird!', content: div, html:true, placement:"right"});`

Comment: Unfortunately, something is wrong with the code.The popover doesn't event appear. But thank you for your suggestion :)