# Bootstrap with JS, result of a function in popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code to get temperature of London from weather API. It works correctly (images are local hence won't show):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css" />

        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function foo(callback) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: callback
                });
            }

            function myCallback(result) {
                var temp = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.main.temp));
                var Kelvin = 272;
                var Centigrade = Math.round(temp-Kelvin);

                if (Centigrade <= 25) {
                    //alert("Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C");
                    var temp = document.getElementById("temp");
                    temp.style.fontSize = "20px";
                    temp.innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , Cool&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo2.svg\"/>";
                    //document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , Cool&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo2.svg\"/>";
                }
                else if (Centigrade > 25) {
                    var temp = document.getElementById("temp");
                    temp.style.fontSize = "20px";
                    temp.innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , Cool&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo3.svg\"/>";
                    //document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = Centigrade+"° C , It's Hot !!! "+"<img src= \"img/Tlogo3.svg\"/>";
                }
            }
        </script>

        <div style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 75px;"> 
            <img src="img/temlogo.svg" width="35" height="35" onclick="foo(myCallback);"/>
        </div>

        <p id="temp"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

From tutorials point and Bootstrap website I have tried to use a dissmissable popover. It works fine too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Temperature" data-content="40C">Temperature</a>
</html>
```

Now what I am trying is I want get temperature as popover element. ie. if I click on image button, it should trigger temperature acquiring function and then show the temperature and the image related to that in popover box. So here is two challenge I am facing.

1. Setting a image instead of the red button and then temperature data
2. List item and the image ie. `Tlogo2.svg` to be appeared in that pop over box.

So can anyone suggest how to set that?

**EDIT : I have tried this to attain what I said. but nothing happened. The code goes here:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//Function
function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: callback
    });
}

function myCallback(result) {
var temp = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.main.temp));
var Kelvin = 272;
var Centigrade = temp-Kelvin;
alert("Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C");
//document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C";
}

        $(function() {
            $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(myCallback(result));
        });
    </script>
</body>
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Temperature" data-content="40C">Temperature</a>

</html>
```

**I am adding some addition. SO that people don't get confuse and see what really I want. I want the result of the function ie temperature is 23 C to that pop over element
The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//Function

function foo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: callback
    });
}

function myCallback(result) {
var temp = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.main.temp));
var Kelvin = 272;
var Centigrade = temp-Kelvin;
alert("Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C");
//document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Temperature : "+Math.round(Centigrade)+" C";
}


$(function() {
                $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(myCallback);
            });
    </script>
</body>
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Temperature" data-content= "myCallback(result);" >Temperature</a>

</html>
```

So let me know where I need to change.

Comment: check this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130069/load-a-bootstrap-popover-content-with-ajax-is-this-possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do popover on hover, here is example

```
  $(function() {
      $('[title]').attr("data-rel", "tooltip");
      $("[data-rel='tooltip']")
          .attr("data-placement", "top")
          .attr("data-content", function() {
              return $(this).attr("title")
          })
          .removeAttr('title');


      var showPopover = function() {
          $(this).popover('show');
      };
      var hidePopover = function() {
          $(this).popover('hide');
      };
      $("[data-rel='tooltip']").popover({
          trigger: 'manual'
      }).click(showPopover).hover(showPopover, hidePopover);

  });
```

Use it like this

```
 <a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" title="40c">Temperature</a>
```

Comment: Not related to my solution.