# AJAX request to insert data into bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an AJAX request that gets data from a page and should insert it into a bootstrap popover, but it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#req').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "/requests",
    success: function(data){
        var page = $(data);
        var req = page.find('#reqP').html();
        console.log(req);
        return $(req).html();
        }
    });
    }
  });
});
```

This gets the data fine and logs to the console, but it does not show up in the popover. I'm new to JS, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Also, in your answer if you could include **why** what I'm doing is not working, that would be great.

EDIT: I also tried to add `return` before the `$.ajax(...)` request, which didn't work.

Comment: I think this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23193877/4316870) could help you.

Comment: @PatrickLC With that, it needs to be modified to only get the content from the one div

Comment: @PatrickLC Can you look at my edits and see if you can better help me with the extra information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lVo8nTE915) shows you how using your idea works for retrieving the login for the html Bootply landing page:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Test:</p>
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
     <a id="example" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Show Bootply Login</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() { 
      var page= $.ajax(
        {url: 'http://www.bootply.com',
         async: false}).responseText;      
      var req = $(page).find('#menuLogin');
      return req.html();
    },
    placement:'bottom'    
  });
});
```