# HTML not working on bootstrap popover when ajax content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using bootstrap 3.3 & trying to show ajax content on popover. Here is my jquery code

```
$('.action_col span').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'left',
        content: function () {
            var div_id = 'tmp-id-' + $.now();
            var tour_id = $.trim($(this).data('tour_id'));
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: site_url + 'controller/tour_details',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    t: tour_id
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                $('#' + div_id).html(response);
            });
            return '<div id="' + div_id + '">Loading...</div>';
        }
    });
```

`tour_details` method

```
echo 'working';
```

This works fine but when I send any HTML it doesn't work anymore. Like

```
 echo '<div class="popover"> <div class="arrow"></div> <h3 class="popover-title">test</h3> <div class="popover-content"> <p>fgds</p> </div> </div>';
```

This is not working. Whats wrong here?

My HTML view file

```
<span data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-tour_id="88">[Tour # 48844]</span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130069/load-a-bootstrap-popover-content-with-ajax-is-this-possible

Comment: @Tacsiazuma Code already taken from the post you mentioned with slightly modified. Now My issue is new and not working

Comment: Remove `dataType: 'html',` from ajax and check once.

Comment: @NanaPartykar yes tested. nothing changes. same as earlier